# error: parse error on input `,' - Haskell

Tags: haskell

Getting the error "error: parse error on input `,'"

When reading in text from a file

With the below code:

`data TextEditor = TextEditor ([Char], [Char], [Char], [Char]) deriving (Show)`

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, in Haskell, function arguments are not separated with commas (curried form).

Specifically, the declaration should read

```
load :: TextEditor -> String -> IO TextEditor
-- The below won't compile.
load (TextEditor (_,s,r,b)) path = do  -- What is (l, s, r, b) here?
    content <- readFile path
    return $TextEditor (content,s,r,b)
```

Comment: @9000 perhaps you'd kindly add the corrected pattern-matching line as well?

Comment: @bipill: I try to understand the intention correctly, that is, the `t` parameter to `TextEditor` type should be a 4-tuple.  It won't compile, though, to my mind, because the first argument of `load` should be a `TextEditor t` for some type `t`, not a tuple.

Comment: @9000 No it shouldn't. It should read as `TextEditor (l,s,r,b)`, for `(l,s,r,b)` is obviously a non-match for a single variable, and I wonder if there should be any more constraints on the variables.

Comment: I receive the following errors with the corrected code:

`* Expecting one fewer arguments to 'TextEditor'
      Expected kind 'k0 -> *', but 'TextEditor' has kind '*'
    * In the type signature:
        load :: TextEditor t -> [Char] -> IO TextEditor t` 

and

`* Expecting one fewer arguments to 'IO TextEditor'
      Expected kind 'k0 -> *', but 'IO TextEditor' has kind '*'
    * In the type signature:
        load :: TextEditor t -> [Char] -> IO TextEditor t`

Comment: Unless it's something of a `newtype` with a quadruple-accepting constructor.

Comment: @Queen567: What is the declaration of `TextEditor` type? Please edit your post to include it.

Comment: @9000 apparently its kind is `*`, so the type reads simply as `TextEditor`.

Comment: @Queen567 it's not the type.

Comment: @bipll updated.

Comment: Okay, so the current version in my, hm, answer should work. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parens `( ... )` to surround a tuple in the type of `load :: ...`.

```
load :: (TextEditor (t), [Char]) -> IO TextEditor (t)
```

Also, you have to indent the second line properly (to have same indentation as first line), or else Haskell will give you another confusing error message.

```
load :: (TextEditor (t), [Char]) -> IO TextEditor (t)
load(TextEditor(l,s,r,b),path) = do
        content <- readFile path
        return(TextEditor(content,s,r,b))
```

Also, there are other type errors (like what is `TextEditor (t)`?) you need to resolve. See another answer for more details.

Also, consider using [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you want more feedbacks on your entire Haskell code, after you got your code compiling.